# Thermography difference between AC current wire and DC current wire?

Tags: ac, dc

Is there thermographic difference between AC current flowing wire and DC current flowing wire? And thermogramic differences for drift velocities?

Comment: What frequency range of AC are you thinking about? Certainly a difference will show up in the skin effect for high frequencies.

Comment: Do you mean to ask: "Should AC wires and DC wires look different in a thermographic survey, i.e. using an infra-red FLIR camera?"

Answer (score 3):

If the wire is not a superconductor, where current is flowing, power is being dissipated as heat. For the DC case you can expect current in the wire to be fairly uniform, and thus a uniform heating of the wire will occur.

For the AC case the current will not flow uniformly throughout the wire at high frequency. Two effects come into play, the [skin effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) and the [proximity effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_effect_%28electromagnetism%29). Pictured below is the proximity effect. If the current is not flowing uniformly then the energy being dissipated as heat in the wire will also not be uniform.

So yes, I imagine the two cases *could* look different, but in either case I think heat dissipation by the wire would be difficult to see with thermal imaging equipment. Even then it will be averaged fairly rapidly by conduction in the metal wire and the insulation covering the wire. So the experiment would work in some special cases, but not in most practical cases.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean that using the same amount of copper to make a flat strip or hollow pipe will give better heat distribution and/or more efficiency?

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer: For what it's worth, the high-current conductors in a switchboard (800A - 4000A) are always in "bar" format - "busbars" - maybe for the thermal reason you suggest. (Also because it's easier to bolt "bars" to each other than bolting pipes to each other!)